# Strange memory leak while passing std::pair as argument

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, constructor, std-pair

A constructor for my object:

```
Visited(/*...*/, unsigned d) : /*...*/, node(new Node(make_pair(d,this))) {}
```

Valgrind claims that:

```
==15806== 112 (56 direct, 56 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 14
==15806==    at 0x4C28C90: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15806==    by 0x405160: Visited::Visited(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, char, unsigned int) (in /home/maxyan/Workspace/Graf/graf)
==15806==    by 0x403C30: Graph::solve(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (Graph.cpp:32)
==15806==    by 0x401A64: main (main.cpp:116)
```

After some splitting, like moving the `node` initialisation to code section and separating `pair` construction from Node construction it appears that Valgrind points exacly at `Node` constructor call (but doesn't go inside).

Here is Node constructor:

```
Node(const pair<unsigned, Visited*>& d) : data(d), marked(false), degree(0), parent(nullptr), children(new Node()), prev(this), next(this) {}
```

Argument is being passed by reference so no additional pair should be created while passing in `Visited`.

Moreover it's not false possitive, as it creates strange behaviour in the other part of the code. Data pointed by different `Visited` pointer is being modified by calling this constructor.

Edit:
Removed the problem with unique_ptr. Strange behaviour from the last paragraph wasn't caused by memory leak. I used `this` pointer to allow access from `Node` to the `Visited` to whom it belongs, however `Visited` constructor was called just before insertion to the `std::map`. Temporary `Visited` object was copied into map structure and destroyed leaving the pointer useless untill next structure was randomly allocated at the adress it was pointing. Imagine how difficult it was to debug randomly changing values... NEVER DO SUCH MISTAKE!

Comment: Of course it does. A naked `new` in a constructor call is almost always a red flag. `std::pair`'s destructor doesn't `delete` the object. (why would it?)

Comment: Show the definition of `node`, as well as `Visited`'s copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator, and destructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use **new** operator, you are creating an object in the heap section. Therefore, you need **delete** it. So, you need a pointer to do this action.

We can store the memory address in a raw pointer or smart pointer. If your Visited class is something looks like this:

```
class Visited(){
public:
    Visited();
    Visited(/*...*/)
private:
    Node* node;
}
```

You can switch the `Node* node` to `std::unique_ptr<Node> node`, this way your Node class instantiation will be deleted automatically when the Visited object dies.

Another approach is continue using the raw pointer, but you have to delete the node pointer's content:

```
Visited::~Visited(){
   if(node != nullptr){
     delete node;
   }
}
```

Comment: ITYM `Visited::~Visited()`, and you also have to handle it in the copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator.

Comment: Right how stupid of me. Deleting nodes was handled elsewhere in my previous approach and I forgot to fix it.

Comment: It happens in the best of families @pkubik